# CLLocationManager move in one direction following straight line

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, cmmotionmanager

I'm creating an app where I have to build a functionality that make sure user walks (with his iPhone) in one direction following straight line for 10 meters. If user takes a turn, an alert pops up or something to get notified.

Can anyone please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research I'm answering this question myself.

```
 #define kDistanceFilter 5
 #define kRotationFilter 60

 -(void)initInfluenceWalkingTest{
     wasRotation = NO;

     // Init and configure CLLocationManager
     if (!self.locationManager) {
         self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
         self.locationManager.delegate = self;

         self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

         self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kDistanceFilter; // update location when user moves 5 meters
         self.locationManager.headingFilter = kRotationFilter; // detect rotation if  user rotates more than 60 degress

         [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     }

     //Start heading updates (rotation)
     if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
         [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
     }

     //Init current location
     if (!self.location) {
         self.location = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
     }
     self.locations = [NSMutableArray array];
 }

 /*
  * Invoked when new locations are available.
  */
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

     CLLocation *location = (CLLocation*)locations.lastObject;

     //Filter location by time and accuracy
     NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
     if (locationAge > 5.0){
         return;
     }

     if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
         return;

     if (location.horizontalAccuracy>kDistanceFilter-1 && self.location.horizontalAccuracy<=kDistanceFilter) {
         [self.locations addObject:location];
     }

     //Retain the object in a property
     self.location = location;

     //we show button when user stop moving
     self.buttonTap.hidden = (self.location.speed>0);
 }

 /*
  * Invoked when a new heading is available
  */
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
     if (newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0)
         return;

     //Use the true heading
     CLLocationDirection  direction = ((newHeading.trueHeading > 0) ?
                                  newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading);

     // Check if rotation was about 60 degrees
     if (self.direction>0 && ABS(self.direction - direction)>kRotationFilter) {
         wasRotation = YES;

     }

     //Retain the object in a property
     self.direction = direction;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the location data continuously and check each time if the user moves on a line. Here you can determine the direction from the first, fair enough, 10 records. Then you only have to check if the user does not deviate too much from it.

The calculation of the direction you'll find here: http://forrst.com/posts/Direction_between_2_CLLocations-uAo

Comment: i make a little mistake in my answare: Not the first 10 records, but the First and 10th Take the record.

Comment: I can't understand how to use this! Do I need to make a subclass of CLLocation?

Comment: No, are category class is used in this tutorial. but you can also make a subclass. And later in your code use this snipped to compute the angle. [code] double angle = [myCLLocation directionToLocation:otherLocation]; [/code] CLLocationDirection is nothing more than a stupid double. So you can replace CLLocationDirection simply with double.

Comment: so I believe we are comparing myCLLocation (initial location) with otherLocation (destination Location) and checking if it makes any angle. If it makes any angle means user didn't move on a straight line. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. But compare the angles with a little bit  more scope. e.g. +- 5 degrees or so (needed some tests ;) ).